# Is there an easy way to parse JSON in Java without using some extra library?

Tags: java, javascript, json, parsing, servlets

I'm really new to JavaScript and JSON.  I am writing a Java servlet that needs to parse JSON into Java objects, but the trick is that I cannot use external libraries such as json-simple or gson.

So I've already saved the contents of the JavaScript file in a String called "contents"...

```
contents = "myVar = " + contents + ";";

BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
Object returnVal = engine.eval(contents);            
NativeObject a = (sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject) engine.get("myVar");

Object[] ids = a.getAllIds();

for (Object id : ids) {
    String newId = (String) id;
    bWriter.write("\n" + newId);
}
```

This will print out all of the names of the various attributes of my object correctly. Thing is, I have no idea what to do from here.  I've tried all sorts of different methods of NativeObject to no avail.

There must be something really obvious I'm missing.  Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: `contents = "myVar = " + contents + ";";`...does *not* produce legitimate JSON. There are no assignments in JSON. See the definition of JSON: http://www.json.org

Comment: I did this because otherwise when I tried to do engine.eval(...) Java would complain that it expected ";".

Comment: JSON is not meant to be `eval`ed. For security-sake it's meant to be parsed. Keep your JSON clean and compliant...it'll save you heartache down the line.

Comment: If you could provide pointers on how to parse it without extra libraries, then that would be more helpful.

Comment: that's what the libraries are for. You don't want to use them? Why?

Comment: I would love to use them!  They've told me at work for this particular project that I cannot.  (It doesn't make sense to me either.)

Comment: Just cut and paste out of the libraries, then.

Comment: Do they know the libs are free?

Comment: That is extremely unhelpful advice considering the size of those libaries...

Comment: yes, they're large. Your own solution will be that size too if done properly.

Comment: I guess the best answer to this question is, "it depends on your definition of easy."

Comment: I meant no external libaries and not writing my own library.  I figured if I can get this NativeObject to tell me the names of the attributes, then I probably can get it to do more.  Apparently not.

Comment: At the end of the day you are going to end up with your own home made parsing library. Which, no offense, will be riddled with bugs and not battle tested like some of the more popular libraries have been. You might want to put your 'convincing cap' on and go talk to your managers again about using one of those external libraries.

Comment: Its better to use JSONParser library to parse your json response, its also have lot of code samples available. Ex. JSONParse jsonParser = new JSONParser(); BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent())); jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);