# Standard way to read streamed Jsons Java

Tags: java, json, stream, jackson, gson

there is a Java Standard way to read/write Json streams **without** using Gson, Jackson,... (other json parsers) ?, Currently i have a file like this:

file.conf:

```
01={"string":"Test","number":25,"array":[1,2,3],"object":{"property":"Jack","subobj":{"arr":["php","java"],"numero":1}}}

02=other json object 

03=other json object
```

I need the most **standard** way, to get a Object (POJO). Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853779/is-there-an-easy-way-to-parse-json-in-java-without-using-some-extra-library

Comment: There is no "standard" way yet, jsr 353 (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353) will define a standard api for event and dom-like access to json data. A jsr for binding to pojos will probably follow once its finished. Until then, whats wrong with using Gson or Jackson?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that 3rd party libraries, just trying to find the standard way... until the JSR gets finish i'll try Gson. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't have a standard class for parsing JSON. That's why there are so many libraries for that ([json.org lists 23](http://json.org/)).

When you really want to do it without an external library you can try to build your own parser using regular expressions and/or string operations, but that would be a terrible idea. Really, don't reinvent the wheel and pick a library.

Answer (score 0):

In plain java API there's not any implementation.

Also, I would not suggest you to create your implementation (parsers aren't so easy to implement).